# "argument of type "double" is incompatible with parameter of type "void *""

Tags: c

I am programming an interpolation method to construct an spline to interpolate a data.

I have the file spline.c that contains three functions the one that allocates memory for the variable needed inside the interpolation method `inimem_spline` and another function to free the space after computing the spline which is called `freemem_spline`. But in this part I have an error:

> argument of type `double` is incompatible with parameter of type `void *`

I don't know where this error come from.

```
#include "math.h"
#include "malloc.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "subroutines.h"

// Libreria para resolver sistemas lineales.

static double *sub_diag, * sup_diag, *diag, *d ;

// Function which allocates memory for the variables used inside the interpolation method
void inimem_spline(int n)
{
    int r = n-2, c = n-2; 
    int i, j;

    d=(double *) calloc(n,sizeof(double));
    if(d==NULL) {
        printf("\ninimem_spline:It is not possible to allocate memory\n");
        exit(19);
    }
    for(j=0;j<n;j++) d[j]=0.e+0;

    sub_diag=(double *) calloc(n-1,sizeof(double));
    if(sub_diag==NULL) {
        printf("\ninimem_spline:It is not possible to allocate memory\n");
        exit(20);
    }
    for(j=0;j<n;j++) sub_diag[j]=0.e+0;

    sup_diag=(double *) calloc(n-1,sizeof(double));
    if(sup_diag==NULL) {
        printf("\ninimem_spline:It is not possible to allocate memory\n");
        exit(21);
    }
    for(j=0;j<n;j++) sup_diag[j]=0.e+0;

    diag=(double *) calloc(n,sizeof(double));
    if(diag==NULL) {
        printf("\ninimem_spline:It is not possible to allocate memory\n");
        exit(22);
    }
    for(j=0;j<n;j++) diag[j]=0.e+0;

}

// Free Space of the Variables used inside the interpolation method.

void freemem_spline(int n)
{
    int i,j;

    for(j=0;j<n;j++) free(sub_diag[j]); 
    for(j=0;j<n;j++) free(sup_diag[j]); 
    for(j=0;j<n;j++) free(diag[j]); 
    for(j=0;j<n;j++) free(d[j]); 
    printf("\freemem_spline:Memmory free\n");

}
```

Comment: You are trying to free doubles via your array index operation of `sub_diag[j]` which makes no sense

Answer (score 2):

Remove the loops and simply

```
free(sub_diag);
free(sup_diag);
free(diag);
free(d);
```

Each `free()` must correspond with each `calloc()`.